# Circumventing access-restrictions In TYPO3 Backend

Tags: typo3

I'm in trouble to build a multilevel drodown menu in a site made with typo3.
I created the pages and organized them in their hierarchy, but the second level of the dropdown menu doesn't appear.
I searched but just find TypoScript related topics, but I'm in an specific environment that doesn't allow me to Code with TypoScript.

I wonder if there is any configuration I haven't seen.

Can anyopne help me?

Comment: That "specific environment" seems being that as "editor" you shall do "admin" work. As the description of your access-rights is not too detailed there might be a possibility, but the cleanest way would be to get the access you need, or you develop locally and deliver your results for implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't think about it. Thinking now, with sure the problem is my "role" at the system. I'll contact my admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use typoscript at all you are only an editor. And it's not the job of an editor to build menus. Go to your admin/integrator and give him the job to display multiple levels.

If you have the possibility to create template records, but the whole configuration is done in a site-extension (where you have no access), you still can create/ enhance the menu and give that typoscript to the developers.

There are contentelements to build menus, but for the page main-menu I never would use them.
A better solution is the usage of menu viewhelpers in the page templates/ partials/ layouts.
My preferred way: build the menu in typoscript in a fluid-variable and use it in the fluid-templates.

I don't know how your site gets it menu. From your description I assume that the menu misses either the configuration for deeper level at all. Or it missses `expAll = 1` so you only see pages around your rootline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just realized my role at the system is editor, so I can't do so much. I'll contact my admin.